# Create tag PathJS?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

I think that [pathjs](/questions/tagged/pathjs) should be created. There seem to be enough posts related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just ask a question and tag it [pathjs](/questions/tagged/pathjs). The tag will be created. If it's useful enough, other people will notice the tag and use it as well.

Comment: I do not yet have 1,500 reputation points, so I can't create a tag.

Comment: @Mooseman: Well then, you have two options. 1. Get 1.5k, or 2. Give an example question link and I (or some other high-reputation user) will create it for you. Also consider retagging some existing questions with it, and create a tag-wiki for it.

Comment: I've created [tag:path.js] (to match the other `.js` library tags on the site).